# What's this error ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'Date' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Getting started on writing basic tests using TestCafe.
Objective open a web page and get its title. Getting below:

```
fixture (`Init Tests`)
.page(${data.baseURL});

test('Check Initial pg', async t =>(){
       await t
        .expect(Selector("title").innerText).eql('XXXXXXX');
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

The error message:
`ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to an error.`

is emitted when TestCafe cannot transpile your test code. This means there is a syntax error in test code.

Your code should look like this:

```
fixture ('Init Tests')
    .page('http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');

test('Check Initial pg', async (t) => { 
    await t.expect(Selector('title').innerText).eql('XXXXXXX'); 
});
```

Comment: That Error is now replaced by
testcafe 'path:`/Applications/Google Chrome.app`'  /tests

ERROR No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive.

Comment: @Biju, the TestCafe command-line should be `testcafe chrome tests` instead of `testcafe chrome /tests`

Comment: Resolved now, its working fine. Issue with browser path